# Efficiently build Android system service component

Tags: android, build, compilation, makefile, android-source

I'm trying to extend Android's *PackageManager* functionalities modifying [this file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.1.0_r3/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/SELinuxMMAC.java):

```
frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/pm/SELinuxMMAC.java
```

When I perform a `make clean && make` after editing the file and I start the emulator, the changes are there, but this takes too long even with the cache enabled. I tried using `mmm framework/base` but it does not seem to rebuild the *services.core* module.

Does anyone know a reliable method to modify a system service and then rebuild efficiently?

Comment: I remember having the same problem, and resorting to build the framework (`mmm framework/base`) and using `adb push` to install the new `framework.apk`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `mmm` and submodules

1. Create the new *classes.dex* for the *services.core* module:

   ```
   mmm frameworks/base/services/core
   ```
2. Creates the *services.jar* file including the *services.core* module that we just rebuilt:

   ```
   mmm frameworks/base/services
   ```
3. Creates the new *system.img* for the emulator:

   ```
   make snod
   ```

   If the emulator (or the device) is already running, you can use the new *services.jar* with:

   ```
   adb remount && adb sync && adb shell stop && adb shell start
   ```

---

In fact `mm` and `mmm` do not check for modified submodules, so rebuilding the *services* module (step *2*) without previously rebuilding the *services.core* (step *1*) module is not enough.

---

## DEXPREOPT

If you see the message:

> Warning: with dexpreopt enabled, you may need a full rebuild.

You have to turn off the *dex preoptimization* performing a `make clean` and then use the following flags in `make` and `mm`: `WITH_DEXPREOPT=false` and `DISABLE_DEXPREOPT=true`.